# Can't install fzaninotto/faker in Codeigniter 4.3.1

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4, faker

I'm trying to install faker in my Codeigniter project , but I got the following error

```
  Problem 1
    - fakerphp/faker v1.21.0 conflicts with fzaninotto/faker v1.5.0.
    - fzaninotto/faker[v1.6.0, ..., v1.9.2] require php ^5.3.3 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - fakerphp/faker is locked to version v1.21.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - Root composer.json requires fzaninotto/faker * -> satisfiable by fzaninotto/faker[v1.0.0, ..., v1.9.2].
```

I've tried running `composer update` and re-running `composer require fzaninotto/faker` but I still got the same error.
What can I do to fix this? Thanks

Comment: I tried using fakerphp/php, but Faker\Factory:: create doesn't work. I also tried \Faker\Factory:: create

Comment: Please, share your `composer.json` file.

Comment: *I tried using fakerphp/php, but Faker\Factory:: create doesn't work.* Statements like "*...doesn't work*" aren't helpful to anyone trying to assist. Always endeavor to provide concrete/explicit unexpected behavior or an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Solution:

Uninstall/remove `fzaninotto/faker` from your `composer.json` file since it isn't compatible with your current PHP version (`8.0.9`) and was abandoned already.

By default, Codeigniter 4 comes with an up-to-date and well-maintained improved alternative [(`fakerphp/faker`) pre-installed/configured](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/29c31173b6ecdd3be75ea69b3f5eb876e7b5dcbe/composer.json#L18).

##### Reference(s):

> [`fzaninotto/faker`](https://packagist.org/packages/fzaninotto/faker)
> *This package is **abandoned** and no longer maintained. No replacement package was suggested.*

[Generating Test Data](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/testing/fabricator.html#generating-test-data)

> Often you will need sample data for your application to run its tests.
> The `Fabricator` class uses fzaninotto’s
> [Faker](https://github.com/FakerPHP/Faker) to turn models into
> generators of random data.

[FakerPHP](https://github.com/FakerPHP/Faker#faker)

> Faker is a PHP library that generates fake data for you. Whether you
> need to bootstrap your database, create good-looking XML documents,
> fill-in your persistence to stress test it, or anonymize data taken
> from a production service, Faker is for you.